# If Userform Multipage Sheet Is active, then execute function

Tags: excel, vba, userform, multipage

I'm trying to have a Userform pull the name of the Active multipage sheet to a specific column in my workbook.   There are 4 pages in the userform which  contain option buttons that feed into the workbook.  The option button data already submits correctly.

I need the name of the page so I can categorize the option button results. Here are some of the ways I've tried.

1. ```
   If Page1.Page.Value = 0 Then
      x.Cells(nextRow, 4) = "Category 1"
   End IF
   ```
2. ```
   If Page1.Value = True Then
      x.Cells(nextRow, 4) = "Category 1"
   End IF
   ```
3. ```
   If Page1.Value = True Then
      x.Cells(nextRow, 4) = Me.Page1.Caption
   End IF
   ```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the caption of [`SelectedItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/selecteditem-property) property to get the name of the active page:

```
If MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Caption = "myPageName" Then
   x.Cells(nextRow, 4) = "needed value"
End IF
```

Or succinctly if you want cell value to point to current multipage name:

```
x.Cells(nextRow, 4) = MultiPage1.SelectedItem.Caption
```

See this informative [tutorial](https://www.ozgrid.com/Excel//free-training/ExcelVBA2/excelvba2lesson8.htm) on the MultiPages object.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to 'SelectedItems' .  This information was used right away.  Also thanks for the link to the multipage tutorial.